# How to build a multidimensional array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to end up with a parent array that has several child arrays to be able to send it in through an ajax post.

My html:

```
<tr class="row">
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="date" /></td>
    <td><input type="number /></td>
    <td><input type="number /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="date" /></td>
    <td><input type="number /></td>
    <td><input type="number /></td>
</tr>
```

My javascript:

```
var detail = new Array()
$("tr.line").each(function(){
    var row = new Array();
    $("tr.line input").each(function(){
        row.push(this.value);
    });
    detail.push(row);
});
```

But this isn't doing what I need it to do

```
detail = array(
    row = array(
        text: ...,
        date: ...,
        number: ...,
        number: ...
    )
    row = array(
        text: ...,
        date: ...,
        number: ...,
        number: ...
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input of what you would like it to look like? I don't see anything wrong with this per se, other than the duplicating keys inside of `detail`.

Comment: Ohgodwhy, the sample is just above. It's the last code block in my question.

Comment: How do you want the json object look like?

Comment: `"tr.line"` - well, you don't have any `tr` with class `line` - so you wont get much with your code - perhaps you meant `"tr.row"`

Comment: `what I need it to do` - you need the rows array to be an array of objects, not an array of arrays

Comment: as an aside ... if the browser doesn't support `<input type="date"` the `element.type` will be "text" ... but `element.getAttribute("type")` will be "date"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result `row = Array(text: ...)` better fits the `key: value` pairs of an object.
html:

```
<tr class="line">
    <td><input name="text1" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input name="date1" type="date" /></td>
    <td><input name="number1" type="number /></td>
    <td><input name="number2" type="number /></td>
</tr>
```

js:

```
var detail = [];
$("tr.line").each(function(){
    var row = {};
    $(this).find('input').each(function(){
        row[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    detail.push(row);
});
```

result:

```
detail = [
    {
        text1: ...,
        date1: ...,
        number1: ...,
        number2: ...
    }
]
```

Comment: This is it!! Thank you!